# I have tried to make a code that on getting input of 2 numbers from the user, generates a random number

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

This is the code I have. The `main.js` file is currently empty I keep it there just for show. The `styles.css` is currently only making the font cursive, so again, I didn't mention it. I hope it can be fixed without major changes. I need it to generate a random number between the two input numbers from a user on the webpage. I expect it to give me a random number between for example 1 and 10. It should give me something like 3 or maybe 7. I ran the snippet and it didn't give me any clear error. It said that there is a code error in line 0 file "".

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Value" id="firstNum"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Second Value" id="secondNum"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Generated Number" id="genNum"><br>
    <button onclick="genRand();">Generate</button><br>
    

    <script>
        var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
        var numGen;

        function genRand(num1, num2) {
            Math.floor(Math.random() * (num2 - num1 + 0) + num1) = numGen;
            document.getElementById("genNum").value = numGen;
        }
        
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DavidBuck I have included my question now. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I am a first timer here.

Comment: If you run the snippet, fill in values and click "Generate", it explicitly produces an error. What error do you see?

Comment: The error I get is -->
{
  "message": "Script error.",
  "filename": "",
  "lineno": 0,
  "colno": 0
}

Comment: The error message you are getting appears to be particularly unhelpful, and not consistent with what I see in a couple/few different browsers. What browser are you using in which you see that error output? What *exactly* are you doing to get that error? For reference, I see `Error: { "message": "ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call",  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",  "lineno": 33,  "colno": 18 }` in Firefox and similar errors, with somewhat different wording, in other browsers.

Comment: I am using safari from Apple on a Mac Book Pro. I just run the code input any numbers and hit the button(generate) and I get the error. I might not be able to open stack overflow for the next 24 hours or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the issues I have found in your code:

1. `genRand` accepts two arguments, but it is called (in the button onclick) with zero arguments. You have to move the code that grabs the values of the two inputs inside the function.
2. The line `Math.floor(Math.random() * (num2 - num1 + 0) + num1) = numGen` is invalid, because when you are doing a variable assignment, the variable has to be on the left side: `i = 0` is valid, but `0 = i` is not.
3. I'm not sure what the purpose of the zero in `(num2 - num1 + 0)` is. Why did you put that there?

Below is a runnable snippet that remedies these issues. Please try to do it yourself first before looking at the code I have written.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Value" id="firstNum"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Second Value" id="secondNum"><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Generated Number" id="genNum"><br>
    <button onclick="genRand();">Generate</button><br>

    <script>
    function genRand() {
        var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("firstNum").value);
        var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("secondNum").value);
        var numGen = Math.floor(Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1);
        document.getElementById("genNum").value = numGen;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Generate

```
<script>
        
    function genRand() {
    var num1 = document.getElementById("firstNum").value;
        var num2 = document.getElementById("secondNum").value;
        var numGen;
        numGen = Math.floor(Math.random()*((parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1) + 0) + parseInt(num1)));
        document.getElementById("genNum").innerHTML = numGen;
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I tried replacing my whole <script> and then separately replacing my function genRand() and onwards.

Comment: Just *doing* someone's homework for them, without *any* explanation is rarely all that helpful, and usually not very effective to help the person learn. In addition, the site has a trivial button available which is "Copy snippet to answer", which would have copied the existing code from the snippet in the question into your answer. You could have modified it from there. Having this in a snippet would have made it trivial for someone to test to see if this worked (which generally results in people responding more positively to your answers).